# Adjusting muffin recipe ingredients when adding a can of pumpkin

Tags: substitutions, muffins, pumpkin

I want to add a can of 100% pumpkin to my favorite bran/ww flour/oatmeal muffin recipe and think I may need to add a bit more dry ingredients. Picture of recipe card is below - hopefully. This is just my second posting at this site. I will greatly appreciate any advice on amending the recipe.

[image: Photograph of recipe card, transcribed below.]

Recipe:

> - 3/4 c milk
> - 3/4 c bran
> - 1 egg
> - 1/4 c vegetable oil
> - 1/4 c molasses or honey
> - 1 c uncooked oatmeal
> - 2/3 c whole wheat flour
> - 1 tbcp baking powder
> - 1/4 tsp salt (optional)
> - 1/2 c raisins, nuts, chopped apple (optional)
>
> Bake at 400 F about 15 minutes

Comment: for the record, no recipe I have seen for muffins contains that much pumpkin per batch, usually it's 1/2-1 cup (or 1/4-1/2 can). That could replace your oil. Otherwise, you are better off finding a recipe that uses pumpkin from the start. It will *not* be "the same recipe you love, just with pumpkin", it will be a whole new thing, so it isn't much different to start from scratch with a new recipe.